# Vue.js obtain toggle button value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I'm using Vue.js, trying to implement a function on the method's object which obtains the value of a custom Toggle button component each time the user switches between two values *Yes* or *Not*

```
 <toggle
   :value="user"
   :options="data.users"
   name="user"
   @input="toggleHanler"
   />


methods: {
    toggleHanler (e) {
      this.$store.dispatch('updateUserField', {
        label: e.target.label,
        value: e.target.value
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: Could you provide more details and more code ?

Comment: As i think your toggle component should have custom change value handler, smt like this - @onToggling. The argument of this handler should be a value.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a computed method to get the updated value. So if user is the value you are looking for, it will be something like this

```
    `computed: {
       user() { return this.$store.commit('/getUser')} //your store mutation/getter}`
```